# Helper to get the raw value of a node field?

Tags: 7, entities

I wonder if something "core" already exists that gives me the raw value of a field inside a node. For that matter I wrote this little helper, but it seems too strange not to be able to do it with a core function:

```
function mymodule_get_node_field($node, $name, $lang = 'und', $key = 'value') {

  if (substr($name, 0, 6) != 'field_') {
    $name = "field_{$name}";
  }

  if (!is_object($node) || !isset($node->{$name}) || !isset($node->{$name}[$lang])) {
    return null;
  }

  return $node->{$name}[$lang][0][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I know is [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7).

Your function makes a lot of assumptions that don't work for a core function.

- Not all fields are prefixed with field_, only those created through the UI. body for example not.
- Some fields have multiple values, your function only returns the first.

If you want a function that makes these assumptions, you could write a simple wrapper for field_get_items() that takes care of that.

Comment: yeah, I know :) This is just a quick and dirty hack that will work on *my* fields, in *my* module. I'd not use that as a generic helper to access any fields, thus my question indeed ;) Off to write a wrapper for field_get_items then

Comment: field_get_items (and a little cute wrapper) is the answer.